Installing libgdal-dev >= 3.6 on Raspberry Pi 4 having OS Raspian 10 (buster)
I need to install the python module GDAL >= 3.6 in a virtual environment on my raspberry pi4 ( pip install GDAL>=3.6) , having OS Raspian 10.
cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"   
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"    
VERSION_ID="10"    
VERSION="10 (buster)"    
VERSION_CODENAME=buster    
ID=raspbian    
ID_LIKE=debian    
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"    
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"    
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

In order to do this, I need to install libgdal-dev >= 3.6 .
Actually I would install python module GDAL by running
pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')

The problem is that when I try to install libgdal-dev, by running
sudo apt install libgdal-dev

I am getting the installation of libgdal-dev 2.4.
I have updated and upgraded apt to get a greater version of libgdal-dev installed, but nothing changes.
So I am trying to install libgdal-dev from debian package at https://packages.debian.org/stable/libdevel/libgdal-dev
Specifically, the package compatible with my Raspberry Pi OS turns out to be libgdal-dev_3.6.2+dfsg-1+b2_armhf.deb.
I have downloaded it from here https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/armhf/libgdal-dev/download.
Now, how can I safely install it?
NOTE:  the fact that by simply running sudo apt install libgdal-dev I could not get the newer version of libgdal-dev makes me fear that the newer versions would not be compatible with my Raspian 10 (buster) OS.

I had a bad experience in building virtual environments in raspbian OS for apps involving geodata python modules. I have decided to install Ubuntu 22.04 OS on my raspberry pi.

According to this thread, it seems it is possible to install libgdal-dev >= 3.6 on Raspberry Pi 4 having OS Raspian 10 (buster).
Yet I preferred to Install a newer version of Raspian OS.
So I have made a backup of all things on my Raspberry Pi, formatted the disk (SD card), flashed the new OS Raspian 12 Bookworm on the disk by using the Raspberry Pi Imager, configured the Pi.
Then I have installed libgdal-dev via
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install libgdal-dev

and I can see the version installed is the 3.6.0
echo $(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')
3.6

